# how to transfer a file through SFTP in java?

Tags: java, file, sftp, edi, b2b

**How to transfer a file through SFTP in java? I want sample code for SFTP client.
I want to embed the SFTP server in my application and the client should able to send a file to my application.**

PS: This was asked for SFTP client. And This question is not a duplicate of other two questions.

Find the below link to implement SFTP.

https://codetransient.wordpress.com/2019/06/22/sftp-secured-file-transfer-protocol/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public void send (String fileName) {
    String SFTPHOST = "host:IP";
    int SFTPPORT = 22;
    String SFTPUSER = "username";
    String SFTPPASS = "password";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "file/to/transfer";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    System.out.println("preparing the host information for sftp.");

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Host connected.");
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("sftp channel opened and connected.");
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File(fileName);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
        log.info("File transfered successfully to host.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception found while tranfer the response.");
    } finally {
        channelSftp.exit();
        System.out.println("sftp Channel exited.");
        channel.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Channel disconnected.");
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Host Session disconnected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: my destination directory needs sudo permission any idea how can I do that? @Dhinakar

Comment: what if I don't know the working directory. I know just the file path? How to handle cd command then?

Comment: @Ajak6 Did you find a solution for having sudo permissions?

Comment: @DishiJain I changed the destination to a tmp folder and then used jcsh to execute 'mv' command to final destination with sudo. That worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for lame question, but SFTPWORKINGDIR is destination directory or source directory?

Comment: @Jaydeep it is target directory.

Comment: What library is used here ?

Comment: @Dhinakar It is working for me. Thanks .....

Comment: What library are you using for this code? Several of the classes here are not found within core Java e.g. ChannelSftp, JSch.

Comment: JSCH library http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: It worked fine, however it stores file of size 0kb. What can be the solution?